# Problema llave foranea NodeJS Express MySQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de NodeJS

Tengo una tabla clientes con los campos fullname, telefono, direccion, email y tengo una tabla vehiculo con los campos license_plate, marca, modelo, color, cliente_id (llave foranea para la tabla cliente)

Estoy intentando añadir un nuevo cliente a la vez que registro también los datos de su vehículo usando:

```
router.post('/addclient', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    //Recoge los datos del formulario y guarda en un objeto nuevo
    const {fullname, telefono, direccion, email} = req.body;
    //El objeto nuevo se llama newLink
    const newClient = {
        fullname,
        telefono,
        direccion,
        email
    };
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO clientes set ?', [newClient]);
    const {license_plate, marca, modelo, color} = req.body;
    const newVehicle = {
        license_plate,
        marca,
        modelo,
        color,
       //Esta linea no se si es correcta
        cliente_id: newClient.cliente_id
    };
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO vehiculos set ?', [newVehicle]);
    req.flash('success', 'Usuario y veh registrado correctamente');
    res.redirect('/entrance');
});
```

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE SALE

```
code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: "Column 'cliente_id' cannot be null",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO vehiculos set `license_plate` = 'XX', `marca` = 'Mazda', `modelo` = 'Mazda 3', `color` = 'Blanco', `cliente_id` = NULL"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas **pool.query** deberías poder recibir el ID del cliente insertado, por lo que únicamente te faltaría almacenar la respuesta obtenida quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
router.post('/addclient', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
            //Recoge los datos del formulario y guarda en un objeto nuevo
            const {fullname, telefono, direccion, email} = req.body;
            //El objeto nuevo se llama newLink
            const newClient = {
                fullname,
                telefono,
                direccion,
                email
            };
            let nuevoCliente = await pool.query('INSERT INTO clientes set ?', [newClient]);
            const {license_plate, marca, modelo, color} = req.body;
            const newVehicle = {
                license_plate,
                marca,
                modelo,
                color,
                cliente_id: nuevoCliente.insertId
            };
            await pool.query('INSERT INTO vehiculos set ?', [newVehicle]);
            req.flash('success', 'Usuario y veh registrado correctamente');
            res.redirect('/entrance');
        });
```

Para cerciorarte de la información que tienes a tu alcance puede hacer un **console.log(nuevoCliente)**

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos, esta solución fue perfecta para mi.